# How to configure gulp-typescript to work with JSPM when transpiling Angular2 TS

Tags: typescript, angular, jspm, gulp-typescript

We have a gulp script that looks like the following (only the relevant pieces shown):

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const typescript = require('gulp-typescript');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const tscConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');
const inlineNg2Templates = require('gulp-inline-ng2-template');
const paths = {
    distAssetsFolder: 'dist/assets',
    distFolder: 'dist',
    distLibFolder: 'dist/lib',
    distFiles: 'dist/**/*',
    srcMapFolder: './maps',
    srcFiles: 'src/**/*',
    srcAssetFolder: 'src/assets/**/*',
    srcMainSassFile: 'src/**/main.scss',
    srcTsFiles: 'src/**/*.ts',
    srcTestFiles : 'src/**/*.spec.ts'
};
gulp.task('transpile-typescript', ['clean:dist'], function () {
    return gulp
        .src(paths.srcTsFiles)
        .pipe(inlineNg2Templates({ useRelativePaths: true}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(typescript(tscConfig.compilerOptions))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write(paths.srcMapFolder))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distFolder));
});
```

We're using JSPM for our dependency management & have jspm-config.js at the root of our project.

Regardless of what task in our gulp script we run we get the following errors:

> src\app\sidebar\panel.component.ts(1,46): error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.
>   src\app\sidebar\panel.component.ts(2,30): error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module 'angular2/http'.
>   src\app\uiComponents\demo\demo.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find
>   module 'angular2/core'. src\app\uiComponents\modal\modal.ts(1,54):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.
>   src\app\uiComponents\modal\modal.ts(2,23): error TS2307: Cannot find
>   module 'angular2/common'.

However; the app works just fine. At runtime these *errors* are resolved by the map in our jspm-config.js file which contains something like the following:

```
"angular2": "npm:angular2@2.0.0-beta.7",
```

I realize we just need to somehow reference the jspm config at transpile time but I'm just not sure how to do that at this point.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using gulp-jspm. See documentation at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jspm.

First set up your jspm config.js to use typescript as the transpiler and also to recognize ts files:

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "typescript",

  packages: {
    "app": {
      "defaultExtension": "ts"
    }
  },

(...other settings...)
}
```

Then replace the call to typescript in your gulpfile with jspm. Example:

```
var jspm = require('gulp-jspm');

gulp.task("jspmBundle", function() {
    return gulp.src(TS_GLOB)
        .pipe(jspm())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(DIST_TARGET_PATH));
});
```

You can also set up your development environment to configure SystemJS to transpile on the fly. Read more about that here:

https://yakovfain.com/2015/10/13/starting-an-angular-2-project-with-typescript-and-jspm/

Comment: Could you add some more details? This answer is very poor as the question is how to configure it with typescript, not "what library should I use?"

Comment: I added more info. Gulp-jspm was recommended as a way to tie SystemJS configuration into the gulp build process.